# Line Break in cshtml.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, line-breaks, razor-pages

I'm trying to have a line break in cshtml.cs

This is the code:

```
string error ="";
foreach (ValidationFailure fail in check.Errors)
{
     error += (fail.ErrorMessage + "<br>");
}
ViewData["Message"] = error;
```

I have tried `<br>, <br/>, \n, \r` but 'error' still prints out.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it.
I should put a double slash instead of just 1.

```
string error ="";
foreach (ValidationFailure fail in check.Errors)
{
     error += (fail.ErrorMessage + "\\n");
}
ViewData["Message"] = error;
```